# How can I log out a user using another browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpcontext, mediatr

I am trying to log out users if the password is changed. It is working if the operations are made in the same client (working if both admin and user in google chrome, if the password changes it instantly log out the user after the page routing) but if the clients are different it is not working (if admin changes the password from google chrome but user is using miscrofot edge, the user is not being kicked)

**!Note:** I made the test in localhost, not in published version

**!Edit:** In the comment section, we discussed about using a periodic session check from database, I also shared my ClaimModel. Is there any way to use it for preventing the session check ?

**Here is my query file**

```
public class GetPasswordUpdateQuery : IRequest<bool>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Guid Code { get; set; }
        public ClaimModel ClaimModel { get; set; }
    }
    public class GetPasswordUpdateQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetPasswordUpdateQuery, bool>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
        public GetPasswordUpdateQueryHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        }
        public async Task<bool> Handle(GetPasswordUpdateQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var updated = await _employeeRepository.UpdatePasswordByCode(request.Id, Core.Utilities.CryptoService.CreateMD5(request.Password), request.Code);

            if (updated)
            {
                await LogoutClient();
            }
            return updated;
        }
        private async Task LogoutClient()
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            await httpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        }
    }
```

**ClaimModel**

```
 public class ClaimModel
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public List<ClaimOffice> ClaimOffices { get; set; }
        public byte EmployeeStatus { get; set; }
        public byte? RegionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SubscriptionExpireDate { get; set; }
        public Enums.AuthLevel AuthLevel { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public byte LanguageId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public int? TeamId { get; set; }
        public string ClientIpAddress { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EmployeeRegisterDate { get; set; }
        public string CriminalLicanceFile { get; set; }
        public int CriminalStatus { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClaimOffice
    {
        public int OfficeId { get; set; }
        public byte RegionId { get; set; }
        public byte OfficeStatus { get; set; }
        public byte? DebitLevel { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public byte JobType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You need to delete all sessions from the database that are associated with the user.

Comment: I am not an expert but normal one client dont get any information whats going on an a other client if its not running over the Server.

So if you log out the client as admin the session of the logged out client is still active.

I would suggest to make a user login check in the main code based on time or page refresh or something like that.

Lets say admin log out the user and in the client prog is a log out chk every lets say 1 minute the user should logged out latest after a minute the admin loggs out the user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. So in a nutshell, instead of making operations just with the httpContext, I need to make a periodic session check to log out users. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly i think the code is correct but the clients don't communicate directly (only over the server) so one client dont get that it is logged out if the server (the running application) dont tell him.